# How to print PHP array values without square brackets and symbols?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I want to print an  array without printing the square brackets and the word "Array", for example if I do

```
print_r($Array);
```

I will get this:

```
Array ( [0] => Example0 [1] => Example1)
```

How can I get this?

```
Example0
Example1
```

Comment: Iterate over array and print each value.

Comment: @u_mulder Ok, I thought I could do this without loops

Comment: @A.Rossi You can do it without loops but only for one-dimensional arrays. Check the answer.

Comment: @Vlada903 - incorrect, as my answer shows.  you can use `array_walk_recursive`.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix My mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any of these ways should work just fine.

```
// First way
print_r(implode("<br>", $your_array));

// Second way
for ($i = 0; $i < count($your_array); $i++) { 
    print_r($your_array[$i]);
    echo "<br>";
}

// Third way
foreach ($your_array as $value) {
    print_r($value);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The first method works for one-dimensional arrays only. If you have multidimensional arrays, you need to use for loops and to check whether the current element is an array or not and recursively enter into more for loops in order to print out all the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way:

```
function print_array ($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
       if (is_array ($value)) {
           print_array ($value);
       } else {
           echo ($value."<br />");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for recursion, however the brackets around `echo ($value."<br />")` are not needed, `echo` is not a function.  Think of it like `break` `continue` `include` etc.   `echo $value."<br />";` works just fine.  And for us lazy programmers `echo "$value<br />";` is one char shorter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [array walk recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
$array = ['Example0','Example1', ['Example2']];

array_walk_recursive($array,function($item,$key){echo"$item\n";});
// tip use <br> instead of \n for HTML
```

Outputs

```
Example0
Example1
Example2
```

[See it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f165bd32db5161318d4c897797494becc7a2d2ef)

> array_walk_recursive — Apply a user function recursively to every member of an array

So this will seamlessly handle multi-dimensional arrays, as my example shows.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($Array as $key) {
  echo $key.", ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to print the values for each key. You can use

```
foreach ($Array as $value) {
    print_r($value);
    echo "\n";
}
```

This will result in

```
Example0
Example1
```

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too !